# Can't get my stored procedure IF statement working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Stored procedure `IF` statement is not working

```
    @manuel varchar(50),
    @tour int,
    @tourname varchar(50) OUTPUT ,
    @pricetax int output

    AS BEGIN  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  -- interfering with SELECT statements.  SET NOCOUNT ON;      -- Insert statements for procedure here 

    if @manuel = 'no' then 

    SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

    SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


    select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'


    else if @manuel='yes' then

     SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

    SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


    select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = 2525 and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'




    END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put a BEGIN and END inbetween each if and else as below.

```
IF (@string = 'hello')
    BEGIN
       --some code
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --some code
    END
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use BEGIN/END to create blocks:

```
@manuel varchar(50),
@tour int,
@tourname varchar(50) OUTPUT ,
@pricetax int output

AS BEGIN  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  -- interfering with SELECT statements.  SET NOCOUNT ON;      -- Insert statements for procedure here 

if @manuel = 'no' BEGIN

SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'

END
else if @manuel='yes' BEGIN

 SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = 2525 and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'

END


END
```

Comment: @MyHeadHurts There is no THEN in IF - that's only in CASE, sorry.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: just drop the `then` - they're not needed and not supported in T-SQL

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `Begin` and `End` to enclose the parts of the if else if block.

```
if @manuel = 'no' then 
    BEGIN
    SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

    SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


    select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'

    END
else 
Begin 
    if @manuel='yes' then
        BEGIN
        SET @tourname = (select [title] from files.dbo.tours where tour = @tour) 

        SET @pricetax = (select top 1 [adult] from files.dbo.trprices where tour = @tour)


         select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(CAST(ddate7 AS CHAR) AS DATETIME),101) as ddate7 from files.dbo.TDEPART where tour = 2525 and depart > convert(int,getdate())  and status = 'OK'
        END
END
```

There is no Else If in T-SQL, check the edits.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts yes, there is no Else If in T-SQL, check my edits, it should work now (assuming all else is correct)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko not like he did :)